# CASE conversion from IIF

Tags: sql, oracle, ms-access, oracle-sqldeveloper

I started off with SQL (access)

```
IIf(Len([CAT]) < 3, 
Left([CAT],1) & 0 & Right([CAT],1),
[CAT]) AS CAT1, 
[HD0] &

IIf([TABLE].[HD1]<>"00",
" / " & [HD1_ABR],
Null) & 
IIf([HD2]<>"00",
" / " & [HD2_NAME],
Null) & 
IIf([HD3]<>"000",
" / " & [HD3_NAME],
Null) & 
IIf([HD4]<>"00",
" / " & [HD4_NAME]) AS NAME,
```

and did Oracle (Sql Developer)

```
Case
When length(cat) < 3
Then SubStr(cat,1,1) || '0' || SubStr(cat,-1,1)
Else cat
End cat1,hd0
Case
When TABLE <>"00"
then " / "
else HD1_ABR,null
```

When I run query in SQLDev I get error
Error at Command Line:9 Column:4
Error report:
SQL Error: ORA-00923: FROM keyword not found where expected
00923. 00000 -  "FROM keyword not found where expected"

Comment: As a side note, there are no square brackets in Oracle.  Those are used in MS Access and SQL Server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MS Access syntax is entirely different to Oracle syntax. No square brackets, and different names for the SQL functions. http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e17118/functions.htm#SQLRF006

```
 Case
   When length(cat) < 3
   Then SubStr(cat,1,1) || '0' || SubStr(cat,-1,1)
   Else cat
 End cat1
```

Comment: CASE when LENGTH(CAT) < 3 Then Left(CAT,1) || '0' || Right(CAT,1) Else CAT END AS CAT1, HD0

Comment: No such functions as Left() and Right() in Oracle.

Comment: @user2186876 You can use `LPAD` (`LEFT`) and `RPAD` (`RIGHT`)

Comment: what if i have something longer IIf(Len([CAT]) < 3, 
    Left([CAT],1) & 0 & Right([CAT],1),
    [CAT]) AS CAT1, 
[HD0] &
 
IIf([TABLE].[HD1]<>"00",
    " / " & [HD1_ABR],
    Null) & 
IIf([HD2]<>"00",
    " / " & [HD2_NAME],
    Null) & 
IIf([HD3]<>"000",
    " / " & [HD3_NAME],
    Null) & 
IIf([HD4]<>"00",
    " / " & [HD4_NAME]) AS NAME,

Comment: @user2186876 longer than what?

Comment: would I simply add || CAse when then else

Comment: @user2186876 Whatever the length, it's just a matter of using the correct Oracle syntax instead of MAS Access -- the expanded example you give doesn't seem to have any additional elements of syntax, so the answer ought to give you everything you need, I think.

Comment: Perfect the answer is good I am trying to continue on with the answer, I added a Coma ok thank you